# How to make AmCharts 4 legend having a toggleable checkbox

Tags: reactjs, amcharts4

I am trying to set up AmCharts 4 charts witha checkbox legend.

I have set a background image to every legend, but can't find a way to toggle that image when turning on and off the legend item.

```
        // add legend
        this.chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();
        this.chart.legend.useDefaultMarker = true;

        // Remove square from marker template
        const marker = this.chart.legend.markers.template;
        marker.disposeChildren();

        // Add custom image instead
        const checkbox = marker.createChild(am4core.Image);
        checkbox.width = 40;
        checkbox.height = 40;
        checkbox.verticalCenter = "top";
        checkbox.horizontalCenter = "left";
        checkbox.adapter.add("href", (href: any, target: any) => {
            if(!target.dataItem.dataContext.isHidden) {
                return "http://cdn.onlinewebfonts.com/svg/img_207414.png";
            }
            else {
                return '';
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would keep the original marker square and just tweak it to:

1. maintain existing interaction behavior,
2. form the bounding box for the checkbox (note: his checkbox image [image: image of a checkmark] has no bounding box).

When a Legend Item is toggled, its objects are changed to [the `"active"` State](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/states/#Reserved_named_states). So instead of trying to use an adapter on the `href` of your `Image`, create an `"active"` `State` for it in which its `opacity` is set to `0`.

Omitting the adapter (and adjusting the size of either the image and/or the marker's square so they match), here's the additional code:

```js
  const markerColumn = marker.children.getIndex(0);

  // Optionally straighten out the square
  markerColumn.cornerRadius(0, 0, 0, 0);
  // Hide the square
  markerColumn.defaultState.properties.fillOpacity = 0;
  // Form the bounding box
  markerColumn.defaultState.properties.strokeWidth = 1;
  markerColumn.defaultState.properties.stroke = am4core.color("#000");
  markerColumn.defaultState.properties.strokeOpacity = 1;

  // After your checkbox code... again, omit/comment out the href adapter
  checkbox.href = "https://cdn.onlinewebfonts.com/svg/img_207414.png";
  checkbox.dx = 1;
  checkbox.dy = 1;

  const checkboxActiveState = checkbox.states.create("active");
  checkboxActiveState.properties.opacity = 0;
```

Demo:

https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/89495edd36c6bf90d57262e2d7b9c182

Screenshot:

[image: screenshot of both active and default state legend items, checkmark appears in the latter]

Comment: That worked perfectly for my case. Thank you very much sir!