# amcharts - XY chart's legend - possibility to distinguish onclick by checkbox and label

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

Is there any way to distinguish those two behaviors from each other? I would like to obtain different functionality clicking on the legend's checkbox and the other one on the label.

Pic for clarity:

[image]

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at these two issues on **GitHub**:

- [Legent marker event · Issue #3924](https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts4/issues/3924)
- [Question: Prevent default hit handler for legend labels · Issue #782](https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts4/issues/782)

You can do something like that:

```js
chart.legend.markers.template.interactionsEnabled = true;
chart.legend.labels.template.interactionsEnabled = true;

chart.legend.markers.template.events.on("hit", e => {
  console.log("Marker!");
});

chart.legend.labels.template.events.on("hit", e => {
  console.log("Label!");
});
```

If we add the code above to [this demo](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/legend-markers-as-checkboxes/), we get the following result:

```js
/**
 * ---------------------------------------
 * This demo was created using amCharts 4.
 * 
 * For more information visit:
 * https://www.amcharts.com/
 * 
 * Documentation is available at:
 * https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/
 * ---------------------------------------
 */

// Themes begin
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
// Themes end

// Create chart instance
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

// Add data
chart.data = [ {
  "year": "2003",
  "europe": 2.5,
  "namerica": 2.5,
  "asia": 2.1,
  "lamerica": 1.2,
  "meast": 0.2,
  "africa": 0.1
}, {
  "year": "2004",
  "europe": 2.6,
  "namerica": 2.7,
  "asia": 2.2,
  "lamerica": 1.3,
  "meast": 0.3,
  "africa": 0.1
}, {
  "year": "2005",
  "europe": 2.8,
  "namerica": 2.9,
  "asia": 2.4,
  "lamerica": 1.4,
  "meast": 0.3,
  "africa": 0.1
} ];

// Create axes
var categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "year";
categoryAxis.title.text = "Local country offices";
categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
categoryAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 20;
categoryAxis.renderer.cellStartLocation = 0.1;
categoryAxis.renderer.cellEndLocation = 0.9;

var  valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
valueAxis.min = 0;
valueAxis.title.text = "Expenditure (M)";

// Create series
function createSeries(field, name, stacked) {
  var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
  series.dataFields.valueY = field;
  series.dataFields.categoryX = "year";
  series.name = name;
  series.columns.template.tooltipText = "{name}: [bold]{valueY}[/]";
  series.stacked = stacked;
  series.columns.template.width = am4core.percent(95);
}

createSeries("europe", "Europe", false);
createSeries("namerica", "North America", true);
createSeries("asia", "Asia", false);
createSeries("lamerica", "Latin America", true);
createSeries("meast", "Middle East", true);
createSeries("africa", "Africa", true);

// Add legend
chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();
chart.legend.useDefaultMarker = true;

        const marker = chart.legend.markers.template;
  const markerColumn = marker.children.getIndex(0);

  const markerColumnActiveState = markerColumn.states.getKey("active");
  // When a legend item is disabled it triggers its active state,
  // test it out:
  // markerColumnActiveState.properties.strokeWidth = 2;
  // markerColumnActiveState.properties.stroke = "#000";
  // markerColumnActiveState.properties.strokeOpacity = 1;
  // markerColumnActiveState.adapter.add("fill", function() {
  //   return am4core.color("red");
  // });

  markerColumn.cornerRadius(0, 0, 0, 0);
  markerColumn.defaultState.properties.fillOpacity = 0;
  markerColumn.defaultState.properties.strokeWidth = 1;
  markerColumn.defaultState.properties.stroke = am4core.color("#000");
  markerColumn.defaultState.properties.strokeOpacity = 1;
  // markerColumnActiveState.properties.fillOpacity = 0;

        // Add custom image instead
        const checkbox = marker.createChild(am4core.Image);
        checkbox.width = 20;
        checkbox.height = 20;
        checkbox.verticalCenter = "top";
        checkbox.horizontalCenter = "left";

  checkbox.href = "https://cdn.onlinewebfonts.com/svg/img_207414.png";
  checkbox.dx = 1;
  checkbox.dy = 1;

  const checkboxActiveState = checkbox.states.create("active");
  checkboxActiveState.properties.opacity = 0;
  
// ========================= HERE =========================

chart.legend.markers.template.interactionsEnabled = true;
chart.legend.labels.template.interactionsEnabled = true;

chart.legend.markers.template.events.on("hit", e => {
  console.log("Marker!");
});

chart.legend.labels.template.events.on("hit", e => {
  console.log("Label!");
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol";
}

#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<!--
fork of:
https://www.amcharts.com/demos/stacked-clustered-column-chart/

answering:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56652882/how-to-make-amcharts-4-legend-having-a-toggleable-checkbox
-->
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```